# Правильно ли в приложении используются глобальные переменные?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Имеется приложение, в котором активно используются глобальные переменные. Есть опасения, что это будет сильно нагружать систему.

Касаемо того, что при рестарте приложения глобальные переменные обнуляются - ничего страшного.

К примеру, можно ли экспортировать сокеты пользователей таким образом:

```
module.exports = function(server) {

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

    const users = {};

    global.io = io;

    io.set('origins', 'localhost:*');

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        users[socket.handshake.user._id] = {
            user: socket.handshake.user,
            socket: socket
        };
        //listeners...
    });

    return {
        users: users
    };

};
```

;

```
let io_substation;

io_substation = require('../socket')(server);

app.set('io_users', io_substation.users);
```

А после использовать таким образом:

```
var users = req.app.get('io_users');

if(users[req.body.id])
    users[req.body.id].socket.emit('test', 'test');
```

Глобальный io используется же в тех случаях, когда никакой сокет не передаётся, к примеру, когда пользователь отправляет сообщение, но в нём был обнаружен запрещённый контент - текст сообщения пересылается модерации, которая, если одобряет сообщение, то оно обязано быть отправлено заново от имени первоначального юзера в общий чат броадкастом, но без сокета:

```
if(data.specialKey == "key") {
    delete data.specialKey;
    global.io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
}
```

Или стоит передавать в функцию отправки сообщения io таким образом:

```
start_listeners(socket, io);
```

;

```
socket.on('chat_msg', () => {
    if(data.specialKey == "key") {
        delete data.specialKey;
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    }
}
```

Также, можно ли использовать глобальные переменные в качестве временного хранилища переменных? Пример - пользователь отправляет какой-то 15-секундный запрос другому и он записывается в глобальную переменную. По истечению времени эта переменная очищается, но покуда она есть - другой пользователь может ответить на запрос:

```
global.requests.friends[this.user._id] = [this.friend, Date.now() + 15000];
```

Контроллер времени, подключаемый при запросах:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if(JSON.stringify(global.requests) != "{}"){
        Object.keys(global.requests).forEach(function (type) {
            Object.keys(global.requests[type]).forEach(function (requestID) {
                if(global.requests[type][requestID][1] < Date.now()) delete global.requests[type][requestID];
            });
        });
    }
    if(typeof next == "function") next();
};
```

Также приложу полный список глобальных переменных в приложении:

```
var antiDDos = require('rate-limiter-flexible');

global.cfg = {
    server: {
        secretHash: "1",
        secretHashTwo: "2",
        env: 'development', //В каком состоянии находится сервер. production || development
    },
    sessions: {
        key: 'sid',
        secret: '3', //Секретный дешифратор серверных куки.
        cookie: {
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 //Максимальный срок хранения сессии. Сейчас: 7 дней.
        }
    }
};

global.hashAlgorithms = {
    "sha1": [],
    "sha256": [],
    "md5": [],
    "test": [],
    "salt": []
};

global.extensionUrls = []; //Дополнительные пути, которые будут приоритетнее(помогает при ручном добавлении).
//Example: ["someWay", function(req, res, next){}]. Support formats: /someWay, /someWay/. Не поддерживаются глобальные роуты, вроде *.

global.countErrors = 0; //Количество ошибок в текущей сессии приложения.

global.initAntiDdosSocket = new antiDDos.RateLimiterMemory({
    points: 5,
    duration: 2,
    blockDuration: 120
});

global.antiDdosParser = function(key) {
    return initAntiDdosSocket.consume(key);
};

global.versionApp = "3.0.0"; //Версия приложения.

global.openProject = 1; //Переменная, обозначающая статус доступности /game . 0 = Тех. работы.

global.MAXLOGINLENGTH = 15; //Максимальная длина логина юзера.

global.MINPASSWORDLENGTH = 16; //Минимальная длина пароля юзера.

global.MAXPASSWORDLENGTH = 80; //Максимальная длина пароля юзера.

global.messagesTemplates = {}; //Переменная - хеш, хранящая в себе сообщения в течение временного промежутка.

global.messagePreModeration = {}; //Переменная - хеш, хранящая в себе подозрительные сообщения со ссылками до проверки модератором.

global.chatIds = 0; //Текущий id сообщения в чате. Обнуляется при перезапуске приложения.

global.requests = { //Переменная - хеш, хранящая в себе запросы пользователей на дружбу/приглашение в клан от лидера/подачи заявки в клан.
    friends: {}, //В друзья
};

global.streamSubscribers = { //Переменная - хеш, хранящая в себе текущую информацию о стримах.
    radio: {},
    video: {}
};

global.streamersAccess = { //Переменная - дата, хранящая в себе права доступа стримеров на комнаты стримов.
    1: [1]
};

//yaCaptcha и yaCaptchaTrue используются в процессе проверки привязанности номера телефона к почте при регистрации.

global.yaCaptcha = {};

global.yaCaptchaTrue = {};

global.captcha = {};
```

Хочется узнать - действительно правильно ли использованы глобальные переменные и переменные, получаемые через app.get. Если нет - то как, собственно, исправить ситуацию.

Comment: С точки зрения производительности будет заниматься ОЗУ. Но если данных не так много и и они очищаются периодически, то ничего страшного в этом нет. При том что, что `app.set` по умолчанию тоже хранится в ОЗУ.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Глобальный объект users получает все сокеты пользователей и не очищает их, покуда пользователь не выйдет с сайта. С этим как быть то? Если пользователей более тысячи одновременно онлайн?

Comment: Вы сейчас имеете ввиду вот это `app.set('io_users', io_substation.users);`? Если да, то можно настроить express хранить все данные в mongodb.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko И как, собственно, это будет работать? Когда буду использовать `req.app.get('io_users')`, то это ведь не будет происходить моментально синхронно? Или express при каждом запросе на url будет заранее обращаться к бд и вытаскивать данные, только потом обрабатывая запрос? Также стоит ли записывать результат от `req.app.get('io_users')` в обычную переменную? Вроде бы её нельзя потом очистить, тк при любом воздействии обновляется и глобальная переменная.

Comment: А вот как оно собственно будет работать - вам надо гуглить и читать статьи :) Потому что это невозможно объяснить в комментарии. Какие критерии обычности\необычности переменных вы знаете?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Много какие, к примеру, ссылочное копирование переменных. Вот, собственно, переменная users принимает на себя полную копию глобальной переменной `req.app.get('io_users')`, как я понимаю. Чтобы она не была ссылкой на глобалку - нужна определённая функция, как например, extend, не так ли? Но стоит ли таким образом манипулировать в общем целом с глобальными?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Касаемо того, как будет работать express, если он подключается целиком к mongodb, я примерно понимаю и описал представляемый мной алгоритм работы. Погуглив - нашёл не принципы работы, а то, как именно соединить бд и express. В моём приложении, вроде бы, единственное, что хранится от экспресса в монгодб - сессии, но каким образом это всё работает то? Не подскажите, ссылкой?

Comment: Ну я знаю только два типа - по ссылке и по значению. А по обычности\необычности - такого разделения не знаю. Извините, я не понимаю ваш вопрос про ссылку на глобальный объект. Иногда надо менять глобальный, иногда не надо. Зависит от того, чего вы хотите.

Comment: Может, вам поможет вот это https://nodeguide.ru/doc/dailyjs-nodepad/node-tutorial-5/

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Как и предполагал, описанная там функция загрузки пользователя достаёт сначала его, а после уже передаёт старт следующему обработчику. Такой подход подойдёт мне, если хранить каждый новый сокет в бд. Но ведь тогда нагрузка на mongodb базу будет большая, не так ли? Если 1000+ записей достаются при каждом действии любого пользователя? Что в сравнении выигрывает? Постоянная загрузка записей сокетов или содержание их в глобальной переменной?

Comment: Тут зависит от того, чего у вас "больше" на сервере. Если процессора, то вытаскивайте всегда, если памяти, то храните в памяти все.